# Dealing with "Identify YouTuber video soundtrack" questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

According to new YouTube policies and explosion of YouTube "claims", it will be extremely unlikely to have uncredited actual copyrighted songs as soundtrack of YouTube videos. Indeed, if a YouTube creator uses a copyrighted song for a video soundtrack, all incomes are lost.

When someone asks to identify a song which is soundtrack of a video from a YouTuber, two cases can most likely occur:

- YouTuber uses a song from [YouTube Audio Library](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music). So unless someone volunteers to listen to thousands of songs to find the good one, I suggest to close the question and suggest OP, in the comments, to go to YouTube Audio Library website.
- YouTuber uses a copyrighted song (and accepts to lose all potential incomes) and the song is credited in the comments. Close the question for lack of research and suggest OP to check the credits of the video.

I don't see any reason to keep these questions open.

Comment: It sounds like someone needs to talk to SoundHound et al and get them to add the YouTube audio library files to their library of known/identifiable songs.

Comment: @Donald.McLean, I think Library music is not supposed to be identifiable. I don't understand why people are obsessed about identifying it...

Comment: Perhaps so, but there's no telling what songs will speak to people at a deep, personal level - even if they are "throw away" library instrumentals.

Comment: @Donald.McLean, please, you mods need to do something about it, things are getting out of hand. There are too many questions everyday about ID youtube soundtracks.

Answer (score 4):

Youtube is working on a system called [**Content ID**](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370?hl=en) to help copyright owners.

> Videos uploaded to YouTube are scanned against a database of files that have been submitted to us by content owners.

Content owners will now be able to track down their property and act according to their will (block or mute the video, monetize, ...) so that will more and more unlikely for "professional" YouTubers to enclose copyrighted audio to their soundtrack. But even if they still do and copyright owners allow the audio content, the credits will appear in the video description.

YouTubers will more and more use free or un-copyrighted content and they will be invited to use YouTube's own [Audio Library](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music).

**It will be almost impossible to identify unidentified soundtrack on a video from a YouTuber.**

So I suggest we close these questions.

Comment: @Brahadeesh, yeah, this one amongst others.

Comment: I'm actually on the fence about this.  While the argument makes sense, it doesn't necessarily seem to me to rise to the level of requiring a policy.  But since it seems to be causing issues, I'll vote for it

Comment: As you wish @ChrisSunami, but I predict that we will be invaded by YouTube soundtrack ID questions, especially now that video producers will use library music that are almost-soundalikes of famous songs. Almost every question is about YouTube soundtrack now.

Comment: @Bebs - that's a bit of an exaggeration, but I've voted for your proposal.

Comment: I'm still struggling, how this is compatible with the bunch of identify tags, where a missing youtube link may also qualify as close reason. Looks suspiciously like catch-22 for me.

Comment: @guidot, we don't say that YouTube is forbidden. There could have other reasons to enclose a YouTube link than identifying the soundtrack of the video.