# Jincheng Zhang - standard response

Tags: discussion

The mods and the wider community do a good job with the posts we get related to work by Jincheng Zhang.

I guess there a lot of musicians who do what Zhang does with freely available tracks from YTL.  is it worth us as a community adding a paragraph related to the use of library music to the Meta for the site ? This would be partly to educate people that a lot of music out there is either library music or based on it, but also to avoid too much time being spent on what are likely to be unanswerable questions.  As a step in that direction, maybe an extra tag "library music".

I hope my question here is answerable... but also wanting to get some discussion going.   My personal opinion is that questions where library music is involved should not be turned down flat, because every once in a while they are answerable - but we should have a stock response or statement in the help that chances of a positive Id are low.

Comment: Related: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/dealing-with-identify-youtuber-video-soundtrack-questions

Comment: I already gave my opinion when it comes to identify YouTube video soundtracks. New YouTube rules make it pretty clear about what should be done but, sadly, mods didn't agree with me.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the other topic, when it comes to identifying YouTube videos sountracks, we should close them. YouToube is enforcing recognition of copyrighted music so, either the track will appear on the description or the video closed, either the song comes from YouTube library and OP needs to make the effort of looking for it. We need a close reason specifically for these cases.