# Let's add an off-topic close reason for YouTube video soundtrack ID questions

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, vote-to-close

We regularly receive questions asking to identify songs used as soundtracks in YouTube videos. [This Q&A](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/3955) posted on our Meta nearly a year ago explain very well the reasons for why such questions should be considered off-topic on our site. Considering the upvotes on that proposal, it's a good idea to now solidify this as site policy by having a dedicated off-topic close reason for such questions.

Please give your suggestions for the wording of the close reason in the answers (one suggestion per answer), so that community members can vote on their preferred formulation. Feedback is welcome in the comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Questions seeking to identify soundtracks on YouTube videos are off-topic. You may be able to find your song in YouTube's Audio Library.

Comment: This close reason has now been added.